# List Index is Out of Range - Python

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

I have this common error in this *forloop* code and would love someone's assistance.

```
m, n = 100, 4
x = np.ones(n)
for i in range(m):
    y_1 = my_func(x, i)
    y_2 = my_func(y_1, i+1)
    R = 2*y_2 - y_1
    R12 = 0.5*(x - R)
```

I realise that I got this error because of the *i+1* but I do not know how to fix it. What I intend to do is to apply *my_func* to all the m in pairs. That is, apply the *my_func* to m=0, and then m=1, and loop it until I get to 100. Once I get to 100, I want the *forloop* to apply it to m=100, and then m=0. But I am getting this error of *list index out of range*.

I will appreciate any kind assistance in this regard.

Comment: Do you want it to apply to m = 100 and m = 1, or m = 100 and m = 0? The latter would be wrapping around, and you can change `i + 1` to `(i + 1) % m`.

Comment: Yea. I actually meant the latter. Your suggestion is spot on! Thanks, Mario Ishac

Answer (score 0):

you get this because when the loop reach the end of the list it adds 1 .for example if your list has only 10 items your function will indicate 11 so you will have an error
to answer your question , you can use the code below :

```
m, n = 100, 4
x = np.ones(n)
for i in range(m-1):
    y_1 = my_func(x, i)
    y_2 = my_func(y_1, i+1)
    R = 2*y_2 - y_1
    R12 = 0.5*(x - R)
```